# How do you generate a data frame with certain properties in QuickCheck

Tags: r, dataframe, quickcheck

I'd like to generate a data.frame using the [QuickCheck R library](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/quickcheck). The data.frame must have some non-random named columns that must have a certain type. When you run `rdata.frame` you get a completely random data.frame, with column names like `col.1, col.2, ...` which is not the goal.

For example the data frame below has two columns (x and y) with the types integer and factor.

```
> data.frame(x=1:10, y=rep(F, 10))
    x     y
1   1 FALSE
2   2 FALSE
3   3 FALSE
4   4 FALSE
5   5 FALSE
6   6 FALSE
7   7 FALSE
8   8 FALSE
9   9 FALSE
10 10 FALSE
```

I could do something like

```
> data.frame(x=rinteger(size=~10), y=rlogical(size=~10), z=rdouble(size=~10))
     x     y          z
1  -94 FALSE   7.124120
2  -64 FALSE -47.855625
3  -87 FALSE  -9.622184
4   -9 FALSE -28.678583
5  -78  TRUE  35.932244
6  -96  TRUE 116.449312
7  -63  TRUE  51.389978
8   65  TRUE -65.566058
9   71 FALSE 248.323594
10 -76  TRUE 138.238654
```

Which generates the expected format (a data.frame with the correct column names with random data of a specific type).
But it seems to me that there must be a better way, since the number of rows is unimportant here.

It's fairly common to have a data.frame that adheres to certain properties as the input to functions, unfortunately the documentation is really cryptic on this part.

Bonus: how do you merge in certain constant values with this data.frame? (e.g. have a column u with values all 0, in addition to the randomly generated data).

Comment: Your question is pretty cryptic. I don't understand what you are actually asking.

Comment: I want quickcheck to generate a data.frame with some non-random named columns with random contents of a specific type (e.g. numeric/factor etc). I'll see if I can formulate it better.

Comment: One thing I'd like to  suggest is to explain what you mean by "the number of rows is unimportant". Would you like to randomize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(quickcheck)
library(functional)
nr = rsize() # random number of rows
generators.nr = 
  lapply(
    list(ri = rinteger, rd = rdouble, rl = rlogical), #all the ones you need
    Curry, 
    size = ~nr) 
with(
  generators.nr, 
  data.frame(x = ri(), y = rd(), z = rl(), w = 1))
```